# Vue: How to mock Auth0 for testing with Vitest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, auth0, vitest

I am trying to test a Vue component with Vitest but in order to do that I need to mock auth0

Below is my Navbar.test.ts file, however when I run the test I keep getting the following error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mockReturnValue'` as `useAuth0` seems to be undefined even though I am imported it at the top of the page.  Maybe I'm just not understanding the mocking side of it very well but any help would be appreciated.

```
import { vi } from 'vitest'
import { ref } from "vue";
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar.vue";

const user = {
    email: "user@test.com",
    email_verified: true,
    sub: ""
};

vi.mock("@auth0/auth0-vue");

const mockedUseAuth0 = vi.mocked(useAuth0, true);

describe("NavBar.vue", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockedUseAuth0.mockReturnValue({
            isAuthenticated: ref(true),
            user: ref(user),
            logout: vi.fn(),
            loginWithRedirect: vi.fn(),
            ...
            isLoading: ref(false),
        });
    });

    it("mounts", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(NavBar, {
            props: { },
        });

        expect(wrapper).toBeTruthy();
    });

    afterEach(() => vi.clearAllMocks());
});
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Mocking `auth0.useAuth0`

To access the mocked module, import the *whole module* with a wildcard import, and avoid named imports. Also, [`vi.mocked()`](https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-mocked) is just a helper for TypeScript support. It doesn't mock anything.

So instead of this:

```js
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue' ❌

vi.mock('@auth0/auth0-vue')
const mockedUseAuth0 = vi.mocked(useAuth0, true) ❌
```

...do this:

```js
import * as auth0 from '@auth0/auth0-vue' ✅

vi.mock('@auth0/auth0-vue')
```

Then, mock `useAuth0` by attaching a property directly to the mocked `auth0` import:

```js
describe('NavBar.vue', () => {
  it('does something', async () => {
                      
    (auth0 as any).useAuth0 = vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
      // relevant fields for test
    });
  })
})
```

The value of `useAuth0` should be a mock function ([`vi.fn()`](https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-fn)) that [returns](https://vitest.dev/api/#mockreturnvalue) the fields relevant to the test. Assuming the component under test is [`NavBar.vue` from Auth0's sample app](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/components/NavBar.vue), one could write a test to verify the login button calls `loginWithRedirect`. That button is only available [when `isAuthenticated` and `isLoading` are false](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/blob/c584a3c/01-Login/src/components/NavBar.vue#L25-L31). Note the fields do not need to be Vue `ref`s.

So such a test could look like this:

```js
describe('NavBar.vue', () => {
  it('login button invokes useAuth.loginWithRedirect', async () => {
    const loginWithRedirect = vi.fn();
    (auth0 as any).useAuth0 = vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
      isAuthenticated: false,
      isLoading: false,
      loginWithRedirect,
    });

    const wrapper = shallowMount(NavBar);
    await wrapper.find('button#qsLoginBtn').trigger('click');

    expect(auth0.useAuth0).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(loginWithRedirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

#### Mocking `useAuth().user`

One could also write a test to verify the authenticated user's details are shown in the component. Specifically, the [user's name is shown in `.user-info`](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/blob/c584a3c/01-Login/src/components/NavBar.vue#L48), and the [user's picture is shown in `.user-info img`](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/blob/c584a3c/01-Login/src/components/NavBar.vue#L40-L45) when `isAuthenticated` is true. The mocked `useAuth0` should thus return `isAuthenticated` and `user` as follows:

```js
describe('NavBar', () => {
  it('authenticated user details are shown', async () => {
    const user = {
      name: 'john@gmail.com',
      picture: 'https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/1f9d9a9efc2f523b2f09629444632b5c?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fjo.png',
    };

    (auth0 as any).useAuth0 = vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
      isAuthenticated: true,
      user,
    });

    const wrapper = shallowMount(NavBar);

    expect(wrapper.find('.user-info').text()).toBe(user.name);
    expect(wrapper.find('.user-info img').attributes('src')).toBe(user.picture);
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-mock-auth0-v3?file=src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2FNavBar.spec.ts)